# Sorting my BDGrid using SQL

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I want to sort tblMArtha to the infromation inserted by the user in the cbb and edits. But when I run this he only sorts the last edits information. I would like to use SQL but it didnt work so this is my best attempt.

```
    with dmInwoners do
    begin
    tblMArtha.Filtered := False ;

    if edtName.Text = '' then
     begin
     end
    else
    begin
      sString := edtName.Text ;
      tblMArtha.Filter := 'Name LIKE ' + QuotedStr('%' + sString + '%')  ;
    end;

    if cbbRoom.Text = '' then
     begin
     end
    else
    begin
     sString := cbbRoom.Text ;
     tblMArtha.Filter := 'Room No=' + QuotedStr(sString)  ;
    end;

    if edtBed.Text = '' then
     begin  
     end
    else
     begin
      sString := edtBed.Text ;
      tblMArtha.Filter := 'Bed no=' + QuotedStr(sString)  ;
    end;

    if edtDiagnosis.Text = '' then
     begin
     end
    else
     begin
      sString := edtDiagnosis.Text ;
      tblMArtha.Filter := 'Diagnosis=' + QuotedStr(sString) ;
     end;

    if edtAge.Text = '' then
     begin
     end
   else
    begin
     sString := edtAge.Text ;
     tblMArtha.Filter := 'Age=' + QuotedStr(sString)  ;
    end;

   if cbbFrail.Text = '' then
    begin
    end
   else
    begin
     sString := cbbFrail.Text ;
     tblMArtha.Filter := 'Frail=' + QuotedStr(sString)  ;
    end;

  if cbbSelfWalking.Text = '' then
   begin
   end
  else
   begin
    sString := cbbSelfWalking.Text ;
    tblMArtha.Filter := 'Self Walking=' + QuotedStr(sString)  ;
   end;

  if cbbVeryFrail.Text = '' then
   begin
   end
  else
   begin
    sString := cbbVeryFrail.Text ;
    tblMArtha.Filter := 'Very Frail=' + QuotedStr(sString)  ;
   end;

  if cbbRemarks.Text = '' then
   begin
   end
  else
   begin
    sString := cbbRemarks.Text ;
    tblMArtha.Filter := 'Remarks=' + QuotedStr(sString)  ;
   end;

   tblMArtha.Sort := 'Num ASC'    ;
   tblMArtha.Filtered := True ;
   frmSoek.Close ;

  end;
 end ;
```

Comment: What Delphi datasetype is your tblMArtha? Readers should not have to guess details like that. And what exactly do you mean by "he only sorts the last edits information"?

Comment: I would do this in sql but you said it did not work, maybe if you show your code we can see what is wrong with it

Comment: My database has boolean and string an autonum. This is for a school project... I have to use SQL in delphi code. And what I mean with only the last edits is he only sorts accourding to the 'Remarks' field.

Comment: there is nothing in your code to sort on remarks field, only on a num field. But there is filtering in your code and it will indeed filter only on the remarks field because that is how you programmed it. Check my answer to fix the filtering. About sorting there is nothing at all  about sorting on the remarks field in your code !

Comment: for an example on how to do it using sql you will need to tell me what database u are using and what database components you are using, you did not provide enough information to help you

Answer (score 1):

you are overwriting your filter every time, you need something like :

```
if edtName.Text <> '' then
begin
  sString := edtName.Text ;
  tblMArtha.Filter := 'Name LIKE ' + QuotedStr('%' + sString + '%')  ;
end;

if cbbRoom.Text <> '' then
begin
 sString := cbbRoom.Text ;

 if tblMArtha.Filter = '' then
   tblMArtha.Filter := Room No=' + QuotedStr(sString); 
 else
   tblMArtha.Filter := tblMArtha.Filter + ' and Room No=' + QuotedStr(sString);
end;
```

and so on...